# ShowDialog without Blocking Execution Code but Block UI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

When i use ShowDialog() for showing a form it block UI and Code, but i need only Block the UI not Code.

```
letturalog can3 = new letturalog();
                    (new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
                        can3.ShowDialog();
                    })).Start();
```

This mode not block the Code and the UI.

So I was wondering if you could do it

Comment: If the code you do not want to block is in other thread, you already do it. The show dialog will only block the thread it is called on.

Comment: Yes, but i have writed 34.000 lines of code.. Its impossible to change all for 1 showdialog...

Comment: ShowDialog() works by disabling all the windows in your app, then calling DoEvents() in a loop until the DialogResult property is assigned, then re-enabling all the windows.  So you get the same outcome, minus "block the code", using Show() and disabling all windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to block the code, then you want to call `.Show`

In other words, you want:

```
can3.Show(this);
this.Enabled = false; //disable the form so the UI is blocked

//...do our stuff now that code is not blocked while the UI is blocked

//All done processing; unblock the UI:
this.Enabled = true;
```

In fact, that is all that `ShowDialog` does: disable the form, and later re-enable it. In psuedo-code:

```
void ShowDialog(IWindowHandle Owner)
{ 
   this.Show(Owner);

   try
   {
      //Disable the owner form 
      EnableWindow(Owner, false);

      repeat
      {
         Application.DoEvents();
      }
      until (this.DialogResult != DialogResult.None);
   }
   finally
   {
      //Re-enable the UI!
      EnableWindow(owner, true);
   } 
}
```

You can steal all those concepts, and replace guts with whatever you want:

```
void DoStuffWithTheThing()
{ 
   can3.Show();

   try
   {
      //Disable the owner form 
      this.Enabled = false;

      //todo: Solve the P=NP conjecture
   }
   finally
   {
      //Re-enable the UI!
      this.Enabled = true;
   } 
}
```